# How can I add a property to a new node when using onConnectOrCreate in Neo4j GraphQL?

Tags: neo4j, graphql

I'm using Neo4j's GraphQL library, trying to use connectOrCreate for a new Image, which is defined like this:

```
type Image {
    id: ID! @id(autogenerate: true),
    url: String! @unique, 
    creator: User! @relationship(type: "CREATED_BY", direction: OUT),
}
```

And based on the documentation on the Neo4j website, I should be able to say if a node with the url field is not found, then create one and set some properties. Like this:

```
mutation NEW_POST {
  createPosts(input: { images: { 
    connectOrCreate: [{ 
      where: { node: { url: "https://picsum.photos/600" }}
      onCreate: { where: { node: { creator: { node: { id: "userId"}}}}},
    }]}}){
  posts {
    id
    }
  }
}
```

However, for the onCreate Field Input, my only options are `id` and `url`. Meaning, I can't actually add the creator property like I do here.

`"Field \"creator\" is not defined by type \"ImageOnCreateInput\".",`

Do you think this is intended, or any idea where I should look for guidance?
I'm looking at this documentation: https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/mutations/create/ which shows `onCreate: { node: { title: "Forrest Gump" } }` achieving what I hope to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the node with the url `https://picsum.photos/600` does not exist, a new node node with the information provided in the `onCreate` part of the mutation will be created. This "onCreate" node (with `ImageOnCreateInput`) will automatically connect the node that is specified as the "anchor". See my comments in the slightly modified mutation that you provided:

```
mutation NEW_POST {
  createPosts(
    input: {
      id: "userId"     // Note this 'id' here. This is the 'anchor' node.
      images: {
        connectOrCreate: [
          {
            where: { node: { url: "https://picsum.photos/600" } }
            onCreate: { node: { name: "the name" } }       // If the node with "https://picsum.photos/600" does not exist, this will create a Post with "the name" and also connect it to the anchor node with id "userId".
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ) {
    posts {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

You can experiment and play with the typeDefs and mutation provided in the documentation (https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/mutations/create/#_connectorcreate_relationships) to see how the `connectOrCreate` relationship mutation is operating.

Comment: Hi Thomas - Thank you for answering, unfortunately removing the `where` and matching your format didn't solve it. If you look at the image of the schema for `createPosts` you will see the only two options for fields I have are `id` and `url`, meaning I couldn't use something else that's a property of the type. Do you think this is a bug?